# Fix the find failed issue in sikuli script

Tags: python, python-3.x, sikuli, sikuli-x

I have the following code that always returns a findfailed error when it doesn't find the `end_turn` image.

```
def clickCards():
    # region.wait(end_turn,90)
    # search for the cards and click all of them
    if exists(zero):
        z = region.findAll(zero)
        for i in z:
            click(i)
            sleep(1)
    else:
        pass
                     
    if exists(one): 
        o = region.findAll(one)
        for i in o:
            click(i)
            sleep(1)
    else:
        pass

    click(end_turn)

while exists(level):
    
    with region:
        
        if exists(end_turn):
            clickCards()
        elif exists(victory):
           click(victory)
        else:
            wait(end_turn,90)
```

I am trying to automate the following game visual:

- Card Games starts
- click cards while end button is available
- end turn with end turn button
- keep playing until I win
- Victory appears and no end turn button is visible anymore
- click the victory image

The script will run, but when I win it will go into an error that it couldn't find the `end_turn` button.

Error Message:

```
[error] script [ axieTest ] stopped with error at line --unknown--
[error] Error caused by: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Mortada\Desktop\axieTest.sikuli\axieTest.py", line 47, in <module> wait(end_turn,90) File "C:\Users\Mortada\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\Sikuli.py", line 69, in wait return SCREEN.wait(target, timeout) Line 2761, in file Region.java 
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2761)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.sikuli.script.FindFailed: FindFailed: end_turn.png: (129x48) seen at (1439, 676) with 1.00 in R[322,156 1278x763]@S(0) E:Y, T:3.0 Line 2761, in file Region.java
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 actually end_turn and all other variables are defined as snapshots in sikuli and this is why I didn`t include them here in the code.

Comment: Apparently this didn't work as you expected.

Comment: @mkrieger1 exactly, I am wondering why my if statement isn`t working after not finding the end_turn it should look for the victory image, else it should wait for the end_turn image to appear. However it fails after not finding the end_turn image.

Comment: Can you please show the exact and complete error message with traceback that you are getting?

Comment: @mkrieger1 error log added, seems my code logic is not right as the code executes the else statement and as it didn`t find the element it breaks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Luckily the docs are good in this case.
https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/region.html#exceptionfindfailed

Its by design that `region.findAll()` will raise a `FindFailed` exception when it cannot find a match (implicit or explicit). In your case, I think its the implicit call during the `click()` operation.

Fortunately, Sikuli gives a way out by letting one **toggle** this exception.

You can use [setThrowException()](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/region.html#Region.setThrowException) to toggle this exception for a region.

```
def clickCards():
# region.wait(end_turn,90)
# search for the cards and click all of them
region.setThrowException(False)
if exists(zero):
    z = region.findAll(zero)
    for i in z:
        click(i)
        sleep(1)
else:
    pass
                 
if exists(one): 
    o = region.findAll(one)
    for i in o:
        click(i)
        sleep(1)
else:
    pass

click(end_turn)
```